# How to join two tables and select row based on the value (and second highest occurring value) in a column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE tableName 
(
    id  INT,
    customer    VARCHAR(512),
    region  VARCHAR(512),
    cost    INT
);

INSERT INTO tableName (id, customer, region, cost) VALUES ('1', 'EMP', 'Europe', '80');
INSERT INTO tableName (id, customer, region, cost) VALUES ('1', 'y', 'North America', '80');
INSERT INTO tableName (id, customer, region, cost) VALUES ('1', 'y', 'North America', '60');
INSERT INTO tableName (id, customer, region, cost) VALUES ('1', 'z', 'South America', '90');
INSERT INTO tableName (id, customer, region, cost) VALUES ('2', 'z', 'Europe', '40');
INSERT INTO tableName (id, customer, region, cost) VALUES ('2', 'z', 'South America', '60');
INSERT INTO tableName (id, customer, region, cost) VALUES ('2', 'EMP', 'Middle East', '60');
INSERT INTO tableName (id, customer, region, cost) VALUES ('2', 'z', 'PACIFIC', '70');
INSERT INTO tableName (id, customer, region, cost) VALUES ('2', 'a', 'PACIFIC', '70');
INSERT INTO tableName (id, customer, region, cost) VALUES ('2', 'a', 'PACIFIC', '70');
INSERT INTO tableName (id, customer, region, cost) VALUES ('3', 'EMP', 'Carribean', '90');
INSERT INTO tableName (id, customer, region, cost) VALUES ('3', 'EMP', 'Middle East', '70');
INSERT INTO tableName (id, customer, region, cost) VALUES ('3', 'k', 'South America', '80');
INSERT INTO tableName (id, customer, region, cost) VALUES ('4', 'EMP', 'Africa', '80');
INSERT INTO tableName (id, customer, region, cost) VALUES ('4', 'EMP', 'Central America', '80');
INSERT INTO tableName (id, customer, region, cost) VALUES ('4', 'EMP', 'Africa', '70');
```

The customer can have multiple values like x,y,z and also EMP.

I would like to group by the id and get the customer that has the most occurrences. If the most occurrences for customer is EMP, then I would like to get the second most common value. If the customer for a particular id has only EMP values, then it needs to be present in the table. This is my expected result:
[image]

I tried the following where I selected only the rows without EMP, got the highest occurrences and then the rows without EMP and their highest occurrences. But I do not know what the right way is to join the two as I get a groupby error.

How can I remove the duplicate values of id where customer = 'EMP' and retaining the one of the where a particular id has only EMP values for its customer column?

This is what I have tried:

```
select * from tableName where customer= 'EMP' group by id order by count(customer) desc
select * from tableName where customer!= 'EMP' group by id order by count(customer) desc


select q1.* 
from (select * from tableName where customer !='EMP' 
      group by id order by count(customer) desc) q1 
      left outer join
      (select * from tableName where customer = 'EMP' group by id order by count(customer ) desc) q2 
      on q1.id  = q2.id 

union

select q1.* 
from (select * from tableName where customer ='EMP' 
      group by id order by count(customer) desc) q1 
      right outer join
      (select * from tableName where customer= 'EMP' group by id order by count(customer) desc) q2 
      on q1.id != q2.id;
```

Comment: mysql or postgresql? please remove unrelated tags

Comment: @Jens sounds like they are trying to get it to work for both, likely a goal not work pursuing

Comment: What is purpose of ID field - its values are not unique. Should 'employee' be 'tablename' in your SQL? What determines 'first' row - db tables do not have inherent order. Exactly what error message do you get - is it for use of * with GROUP BY? Why should you even need to consider all 100 columns for grouping?

Comment: Sorry, I have fixed the tableName. With the use of group by I get the error 'the column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function'. As far as I understand, if I need all the columns in the end result when I have used a GROUP BY clause, they also need to appear in the GROUP BY clause (similar to pandas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id, customer, region, cost
FROM (
  SELECT id, customer, region, cost, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY CASE customer WHEN 'EMP' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, count DESC) AS row_num
  FROM (
    SELECT id, customer, region, cost,
      COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id, customer) AS count
    FROM tableName
  ) AS t
) AS t
WHERE row_num = 1;
```